# What do the 3 or 4 question marks (???) or (????) mean?

Tags: higurashi-when-they-cry, umineko-when-they-cry

I see these 4 question marks when I read about Umineko (and I think Higurashi) usually on the fandom. (I can't remember where, but I think I've seen ??? and ???? outside the fandom too.)

Eg 1. The [Bernkastel](https://07th-expansion.fandom.com/wiki/Bernkastel) page.

[image]

Legend of the Golden Witch

> Bernkastel first appears in the ????. serving as Beatrice's guest to view her games to kill her boredom. She also gives the reader a hint about Beatrice before leaving.

Turn of the Golden Witch

> In the ????, she speaks to Battler and helps him regain his strength to fight Beatrice. She establishes herself as not just a bystander and wants to help Battler win.

Banquet of the Golden Witch

> In the ????, Bern heads to the world of 1998 and enlists Ange's help in defeating Beatrice and getting her brother back.

Alliance of the Golden Witch

> In the ????, Bern is lying in a bed with Lambda talking about Battler's theories. They laugh them off and then proclaim that Beato shall not win, and a miracle will certainly not occur.

Eg 2. The [Beatrice](https://07th-expansion.fandom.com/wiki/Beatrice) page.

> The ???? has Beatrice inviting Lady Bernkastel to join her game, who decides to become her opponent and help Battler.

> In the ????, Beatrice also invites to her game Lady Lambdadelta, her protector and ally against Bernkastel. Lambdadelta seems to point out that Beatrice made it so that Battler would regain his will to fight on purpose.

Eg 3. The [Rika Furude](https://07th-expansion.fandom.com/wiki/Rika_Furude) page.

> In the Turn of the Golden Witch ???, Bern uses Rika's "mii" and "nipah" catchphrases and acts like they were something Bern herself used to say.

Answer (score 1):

If your played the Umineko visual novel , you'd know that at the conclusion of each chapter, there are two separate unlocks, the tea party and an another thing (a hidden tea party). In Umineko, they are direct extensions of the story and not optional content.

Comment: Ah thanks кяαzєя♦ like epilogues?

Comment: 2nd follow-up question - does Higurashi have this too?